# python: after installing anaconda, how to import pandas

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I have installed anaconda. Now when i am trying to run

```
import pandas as pd
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pandasFile
ImportError: No module named pandasFile
```

It is my first day to python. I cannot figure out how to fix it. I am hoping that I have to change some path somewhere. I know it can be a silly question to post here.

Comment: Try open the terminal and type: python. Should appear something like this: `Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)`. Pandas should be automatically installed by Anaconda. Maybe you have to set it as your default python environment.

Comment: yeah it is showing same "Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:53)". But import pandas command is not woking

Comment: Did you try typing `import pandas as pd` in the shell just after calling the `python`? If it is still not working try reinstall again all the Anaconda package.

Comment: yup after calling the python. I already have done re-installation of anaconda.  but not helping me.

Comment: Try the last thing `conda install pandas`, let's see...

Comment: tried .. but not working.. it says "all required packages already installed"

Comment: :-( I'm sorry I don't know how can I help you more... try to contact the Anaconda support maybe they can help you in a better way.

Comment: no problem.. thank you for your affords :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are facing same problem as mine. Here is the solution which works for me.

1. Uninstall every python and anaconda.
2. Download anaconda from here "http://continuum.io/downloads" and only install        it (no other python is needed).
3. Open spyder and import.
4. If you get any error, type in command prompt

   pip install module_name

I hope it will work for you too

Comment: is it possible to code with Pycharm and anaconda together?

Comment: @KouchakYazdi Pycharm is an IDE while anaconda is a package manager.And short answer,they cound work together.

Answer (score 21):

I'm using python 3.4 and Anaconda3 4.2.

I had the same problem, but it worked (the `import pandas` works now anyway) for me to install pandas with pip by writing:

`python -m pip install pandas`

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

The cool thing about anaconda is, that you can manage virtual environments for several projects. Those also have the benefit of keeping several python installations apart. This could be a problem when several installations of a module or package are interfering with each other.

Try the following:

1. Create a new anaconda environment with `user@machine:~$ conda create -n pandas_env python=2.7`
2. Activate the environment with `user@machine:~$ source activate pandas_env` on Linux/OSX or `$ activate pandas_env` on Windows. On Linux the active environment is shown in parenthesis in front of the user name in the shell. (I am not sure how windows handles this, but you can see it by typing `$ conda info -e`. The one with the * next to it is the active one)
3. Type `(pandas_env)user@machine:~$ conda list` to show a list of all installed modules.
4. If pandas is missing from this list, install it (while still inside the pandas_env environment) with `(pandas_env)user@machine:~$ conda install pandas`, as @Fiabetto suggested.
5. Open python `(pandas_env)user@machine:~$ python` and try to load pandas again.

Note that now you are working in a python environment, that only knows the modules installed inside the `pandas_env` environment. Every time you want to use it you have to activate the environment. This might feel a little bit clunky at first, but really shines once you have to manage different versions of python (like 2.7 or 3.4) or you need a specific version of a module (like numpy 1.7).

## Edit:

If this still does not work you have several options:

1. Check if the right pandas module is found:

   ```
   `(pandas_env)user@machine:~$ python`
   Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01)
   >>> import imp
   >>> imp.find_module("pandas")
   (None, '/path/to/miniconda3/envs/foo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas', ('', '', 5))

   # See what this returns on your system.
   ```
2. Reinstall pandas in your environment with `$ conda install -f pandas`. This might help if you files have been corrupted somehow.
3. Install pandas from a different source (using `pip`). To do this, create a new environment like above (make sure to pick a different name to avoid clashes here) but replace point 4 by `(pandas_env)user@machine:~$ pip install pandas`.
4. Reinstall anaconda (make sure you pick the right version 32bit / 64bit depending on your OS, this can sometimes lead to problems). It could be possible, that your 'normal' and your anaconda python are clashing. As a last resort you could try to uninstall your 'normal' python before you reinstall anaconda.

Comment: I did the same you suggested. Pandas was missing from conda list. So I installed it. Then conda list shows pandas. But when i am importing pandas, I am getting again the same error. Do I have to change the environment manually??

Comment: I have edited the answer and added some further steps you can try. After you entered `user@machine:~$ source activate pandas_env` you should be in the correct environment. You can see that from the first line of `conda list` which should look like `# packages in environment at /path/to/anaconda/envs/panda_env` or from `conda info -e`. The active one is the one with the * next to it. Note that you have to `activate pandas_env` after each restart and in each new shell / cmd-window.

Answer (score 2):

You should first create a new environment in conda. From the terminal, type:

```
$ conda create --name my_env pandas ipython
```

Python will be installed automatically as part of this installation. After selecting [y] to confirm, you now need to activate this environment:

```
$ source activate my_env
```

On Windows I believe it is just:

```
$ activate my_env
```

Now, confirm installed packages:

```
$ conda list
```

Finally, start python and run your session.

```
$ ipython
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem. The environment is active but lacks some package.

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez You've got to be kidding me! This post is over three years old, and you have no idea what the OP's issue was. It is a common error among beginners to install packages to the wrong environments, which is why I detailed the steps.

Comment: Ok. I see, that's supposed to be done by the line that creates the environment, you are assumming it's ok to create a new environment here. I did not run that line,  because I already had an environment with the specific version that I required (3.6). I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

1. Another alternative is to use Pycharm IDE.
   For each project, you can set the Project Interpreter in Settings.
2. For example, if anaconda is installed in /home/user/anaconda2/bin/python,
   you can select the Project Interpreter and set to this folder.
3. Since the whole project is set to Anaconda's path, you can import any module which is packaged within Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX:

I had installed this via Anaconda, and had a hell of a time getting it to work. What helped was adding the Anaconda bin **AND** pkgs folder to my PATH.

Since I use fishshell, I did it in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file like this:

```
set -g -x PATH $PATH /Users/cbrevik/anaconda/bin /Users/cbrevik/anaconda/pkgs
```

If you use fishshell like me, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900256/error-unknown-locale-utf-8-on-pandas-import-mac-os-x-when-running-fish-sh) will probably save you some trouble later using pandas as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same exact problem in that I installed Anaconda because a python script I want to use relies on pandas, and that after so doing, python still returned the same comment that "pandas module is missing" or something to that effect.

When I typed "python" to see which python was being called, I found it was still accessing the older version of python 2.7, even though when I installed Anaconda the installer asked (and I agreed) that it would make its python the default python on my machine (PC running Windows 7).

I tried to find if there is a CONFIG.SYS file on the PC, but gave up after searching in various places (If anyone knows, please tell me). I got around the problem by writing a one-line batch script named python2.bat that called the Anaconda2 version of python, which then worked.  However, it would clearly be better to change the CONFIG.SYS or whatever the PC uses to decide which version of python to call.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are a lot of answers to this already but I would like to put in my two cents. When creating a virtual environment in anaconda launcher you still need to install the packages you need. This is deceiving because I assumed since I was using anaconda that packages such as pandas, numpy etc would be include. This is not the case. It gives you a fresh environment with none of those packages installed, at least mine did. All my packages installed into the environment with no problem and work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only import a library which has been installed in your environment.

If you have created a new environment, e.g. to run an older version of Python, maybe you lack 'pandas' package, which is in the 'base' environment of Anaconda by default.

**Fix through GUI**

To add it to your environment, from the GUI, select your environment, select "All" in the dropdown list, type pandas in the text field, select the pandas package and Apply.

Afterwards, select 'Installed' to verify that the package has been correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, on my Mac at least, was that I opened PyCharm system preferences, then chose my project on the left side.  I clicked on Program Interpreter and looked in the list to see that pandas was not installed. I simply chose it from the list on the right (using the search at the top). I clicked the install package and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

even after installing anaconda i got the same error and entering python3 showed this:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

enter this command: `source ~/.bashrc` (it is kind of restarting the terminal) after running the command enter `python3` again:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

this means anaconda is added. now `import pandas` will work.

Answer (score 0):

pip install module_name will work 
or 
If you are using a file that you were previously working on than just do shift+enter to reload and will do the job

Answer (score 0):

i had pandas installed ('conda list|grep pandas') and python could find it ('python; import imp; imp.find_module("pandas");'

However still was getting this error inside spyder.  I had accidentally been using 'spyder3' instead of 'spyder' command, the former using a different python (3.5) rather than one conda is using (3.8).   Running spyder and things worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed anaconda as you mentioned then simply type in the anaconda command prompt:

`conda install -c anaconda pandas`

as mentioned here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas

Then the `import pandas as pd` will work.