# Pandas installation with all dependencies

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to python. i am using python 3.7 and installed pandas using pip. when i checked for pandas version i found all the dependencies are not installed . so i read somewhere anaconda installation will install all the dependent packages. so i have installed anaconda still when i search for python version it shows that packages are not installed

[Pandas version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QnHf.png)

i am using visual studio code for programming python 
i want to use pandas with full functionality
can someone help me on this installation

thank you

Comment: Did you activate the environment in which you installed all the packages?
check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages
Once you have installed all the packages, use the following command from the terminal --
source activate environment-name

then from the same terminal start anaconda

If problem still persists, check the configuration of the interpreter in anaconda

Comment: This question has been already answered :) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32565302/11261546)

Answer (score 0):

The process I follow:

1. Install anaconda from this link https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/
2. Add the Anaconda program directory to your Path environment variable. See here > https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-add-conda-command-into-the-PATH-environment-variable-so-that-it-recognizes-the-instruction-given-that-the-executable-program-is-already-installed
   Sometimes you may also need to add ".....Anaconda3\Library\bin" as well.
3. Open command prompt and type "conda install pandas", to install pandas.

This has always worked for me.